# Modify window.history.state add a property

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, html5-history

I want to add a property called html to window.history.state so I can use it later.

So I did:

```
window.history.state.html = 'something';
```

But when I go back in history the property doesn't seem to be there.

I tried window.history.replaceState and copy all the state's properties and added the one I needed but first it seems to be making another state push which means duplicate urls in history and also it doesn't seem to work very well.

Is there a solution for this using the history api or should I create a separate array and link it to each pushstate (more complicated) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState),

> pushState() takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.

And then

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by pushState(). Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

So in conclusion, to add a property to the `history.state` object, you need to pass it to `history.pushState()` and you can recover it binding the [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event.

---

#### Update

As said in comments, you need to *update* the state that you already pushed. As you said,

> I tried window.history.replaceState and copy all the state's properties and added the one I needed but *(...)* it doesn't seem to work very well.

I'm not sure about what *doesn't seem to work very well* means, but I'm pretty sure that it's what you need, so I'll try to explain how it really works:

0) At page load, the `history.state` is null

```
console.log(history.state);
// Output: null
```

1) First of all, let's set a listener to the `popstate` event that shows us the current state

```
window.onpopstate = function(s) { console.log(s.state); }
```

2) Then start to push some states

```
history.pushState({first:1}, document.title);
history.pushState({second:2}, document.title);
history.pushState({third:3}, document.title);

console.log(history.state);
// Output: {third:3}
```

3) Then something makes you change (replace) this last state, by adding a new property

```
var st = history.state;
st.myNewProp = "testing";
history.replaceState(st, document.title);
```

4) At this point, `history.state` is updated

```
console.log(history.state);
// Output: {third:3, myNewProp: "testing"}
```

5) Push any other state you need

```
history.pushState({another:4}, document.title);
```

6) Then, the user hits the back button, and the `popstate` event is triggered.

```
// Simulate back button
history.back();

// Output: {third:3, myNewProp: "testing"}
```

7) Then, each time you go back, it keeps poping the states until it reaches the initial `null` state.

```
history.back();
// Output: {second:2}

history.back();
// Output: {first:1}

history.back();
// Output: null
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that I already create the pushState, and I need to add a property afterwards (because some things have changed), before I make another pushState.

Comment: Have you tried to get the state object and use `history.replaceState()`?

Comment: Yes I said so in the question.

Comment: This nicely shows that the pushState and replaceState don't require an url (third parameter) if you don't intend to change it or mutate the current one.